# Using Elastic Search in RapidMiner

Tags: elasticsearch, rapidminer

I connect to elastic search from RapidMiner studio by [CData](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/elasticsearch-jdbc-rapidminer.rst) but I have limit, I can't read more than 10000 data. I fix the elastic setting about this limitation but still I have this problem in RapidMiner.

Could you please suggest me a solution? For more information, I get `"search_context_missing_exception: No search context found for id..."` error when reading more than 10000 data.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 3):

You also have to set MaxResults for this connection.

[image: In RapidMiner Studio under Connections -> Manage Database Connections -> [your elastic search connection] -> Advanced]

In RapidMiner Studio under Connections -> Manage Database Connections -> [your elastic search connection] -> Advanced